# How to export contents of canvas to ps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postscript, tkinter-canvas

I have a canvas in python that holds frames, but when I export to a ps using:

`self.mainCanvas.update()
 self.mainCanvas.postscript(file="tmp.ps", colormode="color")`

and export to pdf online, I get a black screen[image]

The code for the canvas is shown below:

```
Result = Toplevel(self.master)
        Result.title('Result')
        Result.configure(bg='#A8D59D')
        Result.geometry('640x500')
        menubar = Menu(Result, bg='#B3FF00')
        menubar.add_command(label='Export', command=self.exportFile)
        Result.config(menu=menubar)
        self.mainCanvas = Canvas(Result,bg='#A8D59D')
        self.mainCanvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
        mainFrame = Frame(self.mainCanvas)
        self.mainCanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=mainFrame, anchor=NW)
        self.mainCanvas.update()
```

Is there anyway I can include the contents of the frame within the canvas to the ps file?